# How to compile properly for performance tuning

Tags: functions, matrix, performance-tuning, compile

I have a question about how to compile functions properly for performance tuning.

Currently, I am trying to solve an eigenvalue problem of a large matrix. Initially I just used the conventional method to define a function using square brackets (ex. `f[x_]=x`). Now, I want to solve eigenvalues of much larger matrix, and it turned out my code is too slow to solve this problem. I was trying to optimize my code and I got advice that `Compile` is what I am supposed to look up.

Now, this is what I have been trying to do:

First, this is the base code:

```
msa = 10^3;
msb = 10^6;
mu0 = 10^-6;
h0 = 1/mu0;
la = 10^-16;
lb = 10^-16;

aa = la*mu0*(msa^2)/2;
ab = lb*mu0*(msb^2)/2;
alpa = 0.2;
alpb = 0.1;
f = 0.1;
a = 10*10^-8; 
rcyl = Sqrt[(a^2)*f/Pi];


mmax = 49;
kmax = 3;

gx[n_] := 2*n*Pi/a; 
gy[m_] := 2*m*Pi/a; 
gxy = Table[{gx[n], gy[m]}, {n, -kmax, kmax}, {m, -kmax, kmax}];
g = ArrayReshape[gxy, {mmax, 2}];


msg = ParallelTable[
   If[(g[[i, 1]] - g[[j, 1]]) != 0 || (g[[i, 2]] - g[[j, 2]]) != 
      0, (msa - msb)*(2 f)*
     BesselJ[1, (Sqrt[((g[[i, 1]] - g[[j, 1]])*(g[[i, 1]] - 
               g[[j, 1]])) + ((g[[i, 2]] - g[[j, 2]])*(g[[i, 2]] - 
               g[[j, 2]]))]*
         rcyl)]/(Sqrt[((g[[i, 1]] - g[[j, 1]])*(g[[i, 1]] - 
              g[[j, 1]])) + ((g[[i, 2]] - g[[j, 2]])*(g[[i, 2]] - 
              g[[j, 2]]))]*rcyl), (msa*f) + (msb*(1 - f))], {i, 1, 
    mmax}, {j, 1, mmax}]; 
q = ParallelTable[
   If[(g[[i, 1]] - g[[j, 1]]) != 0 || (g[[i, 2]] - g[[j, 2]]) != 
      0, ((2*aa/(h0*mu0*msa^2)) - (2*ab/(h0*mu0*msb^2)))*(2 f)*
     BesselJ[1, (Sqrt[((g[[i, 1]] - g[[j, 1]])*(g[[i, 1]] - 
               g[[j, 1]])) + ((g[[i, 2]] - g[[j, 2]])*(g[[i, 2]] - 
               g[[j, 2]]))]*
         rcyl)]/(Sqrt[((g[[i, 1]] - g[[j, 1]])*(g[[i, 1]] - 
              g[[j, 1]])) + ((g[[i, 2]] - g[[j, 2]])*(g[[i, 2]] - 
              g[[j, 2]]))]*rcyl), ((2*aa*f/(h0*mu0*msa^2)) + (2*
        ab*(1 - f)/(h0*mu0*msb^2)))], {i, 1, mmax}, {j, 1, mmax}];
```

Next, I want to define a function called `sumfunc` as following:

```
sumfunc[i_, j_, kx_, ky_] := 
 Sum[msg[[i, l]]*
   q[[l, j]]*(({kx, ky} + g[[j]]).({kx, ky} + g[[l]]) - (g[[i]] - 
        g[[j]]).(g[[i]] - g[[l]])), {l, mmax}]
```

By using compile, this is what I got:

```
sumcompile = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {kx, _Real}, {ky, _Real}}, Sum[
   msg[[i, l]]*
    q[[l, j]]*(({kx, ky} + g[[j]]).({kx, ky} + g[[l]]) - (g[[i]] - 
         g[[j]]).(g[[i]] - g[[l]])), {l, 49}]]
```

I tested speed of both methods and this is the result:

```
sumcompile[1, 1, 1, 1] // AbsoluteTiming
{0.0154722, 6.39621}
```

for compiled function and

```
sumfunc[1, 1, 1, 1] // AbsoluteTiming
{0.00106203, 6.39621}
```

for the original function.

In addition, I also tried to define a matrix function as following:

```
bxycompile = Compile[{{kx, _Real}, {ky, _Real}}, 
  Table[If[(g[[j]] + {kx, ky}) != {0, 0}, 
    KroneckerDelta[i, j] + 
     msg[[i, j]]*((g[[j, 2]] + ky)*(g[[j, 2]] + 
           ky))/(h0*((g[[j]] + {kx, ky}).(g[[j]] + {kx, ky}))) + 
     sumcompile[i, j, kx, ky], 
    KroneckerDelta[i, j] + msg[[i, j]]/(2*h0) + 
     sum[i, j, kx, ky]], {i, 1, 49}, {j, 1, 49}], 
  Parallelization -> True]
```

for the compiled matrix function and

```
bxytest[kx_, ky_] := 
  ParallelTable[If[(g[[j]] + {kx, ky}) != {0, 0}, 
    KroneckerDelta[i, j] + 
     msg[[i, j]]*((g[[j, 2]] + ky)*(g[[j, 2]] + 
           ky))/(h0*((g[[j]] + {kx, ky}).(g[[j]] + {kx, ky}))) + 
     sum[i, j, kx, ky], 
    KroneckerDelta[i, j] + msg[[i, j]]/(2*h0) + 
     sumfunc[i, j, kx, ky]], {i, 1, mmax}, {j, 1, mmax}];
```

for the original matrix function

For `bxycompile`, it took about 38 secs while `bxytest` took only 10 secs.

This is not what I expected, since speed of the conventional method is much faster than `Compile`. Definitely, I am missing something here, but I am not sure where I am supposed start from.

I would like to get some advice how to compile these functions properly to make the code faster.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, provide _minimal code_ next time.

Comment: For example, the information that you want to solve an eigenvalue problem is entirely irrelevant to the post. It would have been better to explain in words what you actually want to compute here. What is the meaning of the output of `bxytest`?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem of your compiled function is that you do not feed it with the relevant tensors: There are `msg`, `q`, and `g` appearing in the body of `Compile` but they do not appear as arguments of the function. Hence, the notorious `MainEvaluate` will be called very often from the resulting `CompiledFunction`.

Another, less severe bottleneck is the needless construction of the vectors `{kx, ky}`.

As a further general advice, I suggest to start with computations in machine precision as early as possible (unless you do not encounter catastrophic loss of precision).

Here is how I would write things down:

```
msa = 1. 10^3;
msb = 1. 10^6;
mu0 = 1. 10^-6;
h0 = 1./mu0;
la = 1. 10^-16;
lb = 1. 10^-16;

aa = la*mu0*(msa^2)/2;
ab = lb*mu0*(msb^2)/2;
alpa = 0.2;
alpb = 0.1;
f = 0.1;
a = 1.*10^-7;
rcyl = Sqrt[(a^2)*f/Pi];
kmax = 3;
mmax = (2 kmax + 1)^2;
{g1, g2} = 
  Transpose@
   Tuples[Subdivide[-2. Pi/a kmax, 2. Pi/a kmax, 2 kmax], 2];
g1diff = Outer[Subtract, g1, g1];
g2diff = Outer[Subtract, g2, g2];
g1total = Total[g1];
g2total = Total[g2];

gdist = rcyl Sqrt[Plus[g1diff^2, g2diff^2]];
id = IdentityMatrix[Length[gdist], SparseArray, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
besselvals = Divide[BesselJ[1, gdist], (gdist + id)];
msg = ((msa - msb) (2 f)) besselvals + ((msa f) + (msb (1 - f))) id;
q = Plus[
   (((2 aa/(h0 mu0 msa^2)) - (2 ab/(h0*mu0*
             msb^2))) (2 f)) besselvals,
   ((2 aa f/(h0 mu0 msa^2)) + (2 ab (1 - f)/(h0 mu0 msb^2))) id
   ];

sumcompile = Compile[{
    {msg, _Real, 2}, {q, _Real, 2}, {g1, _Real, 1}, {g2, _Real, 1},
    {i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}, {kx, _Real}, {ky, _Real}},
   Dot[
    msg[[i]] q[[All, j]],
    Plus[
     (kx + Compile`GetElement[g1, j]) (kx + g1),
     (ky + Compile`GetElement[g2, j]) (ky + g2),
     (Compile`GetElement[g1, i] - Compile`GetElement[g1, j]) g1 - 
      Compile`GetElement[g1, i],
     (Compile`GetElement[g2, i] - Compile`GetElement[g2, j]) g2 - 
      Compile`GetElement[g2, i]
     ]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Test:

```
r1 = sumfunc[1, 1, 1, 1]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = sumcompile[msg, q, g1, g2, 1, 1, 1., 1.]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Abs[r1 - r2]/r1
```

> 0.000414
>
> 3.17*10^-6
>
> 5.30516*10^-9

Hm. The precision is good but not very good. This might be caused by the fact that you use constants that range over many orders of magnitude.

Similar idea apply to your function `bxycompile`.